# contour integral over line segment and parabola

Tags: complex-analysis

Let  $f:z \mapsto \bar{z}^2$

Calculate integral along

1. line segment
2. parabola $y=x^2$

From origo $z=0$ to $z=1+i$

The first one I parametrized $z(t)=t+it, t\in[0,1]$ and $z'(t)=1+i$. Then used theorem
\begin{align}
\int_{C_1} f(z)dz&=\int_C f(z(t))z'(t)dt \\
&=\int_0^1 \overline{(t+it)}^2(1+i)dt \\
&=\int_0^1 -i2t^2(1+i)dt \\
&=\int_0^1 2t^2-i2t^2dt\\
&=2\int_0^1 t^2-i2\int_0^1t^2dt \\
&=\frac 23 (1-i)
\end{align}

For the parabola I used parametrization $z(t)=t+it^2$ so $z'(t)=1+i2t$. The integral is then
\begin{align}
\int_{C_2}f(z)dz &= \int_0^1 \overline{(t+it^2)}^2 (1+i2t) dt \\
&= \int_0^1 (-t^4+t^2-i2t^3)(1+i2t) dt \\
&=\int_0^1 -t^4 +t^2 -i2t^3 -i2t^5 +i2t^3 +4t^4 dt \\
&=\int_0^1 3t^4+t^2 dt - i \int_0^1 i2t^5 dt \\
&=\frac{14}{15}-i \frac 13
\end{align}

Is this the correct way to calculate contour integrals?

Comment: What's your line segment? It's x=y?

Comment: Oh I forgot one detail!

Comment: from $z_0=0$ to $z_1=1+i$. so that's why $x=y$ yeah.

Comment: Yes, it's correct (if parabola is from (0,0) to (1,1)).

Comment: yeah line segment and parabola goes from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$. Thank you!